# What is this style "* +html .news .image{ ...."

Tags: css, styles

I have in my file "abc.css":

`* +html .news .image{ .... }`

What does this do? 
Any ideas?

Comment: They're selectors. Start reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Comment: @MarcB What's the point of using the adjacent selector after the `*` wildcard though? Wouldn't this achieve the same as `html .news .image{}`?

Comment: what'd be the point of selecting `<html>` explicitly since it's a top level singleton element anyways? It's probably some hacked up CSS to work around IE bugs, since IE for some reason has an invisible/unamed element that exists above body/html that `* html` would select.

Comment: `* + html` describes impossible situation, because `html` node cannot have siblings, since it's a root element in the tree. So this selector makes no sense. All browsers understand it and simply ignore such a weird selector. All but IE7, which due to some bug in parser implementation applies the rule `.news .image { .... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_plus_hack) the `*+html` part is an IE7 "star plus" specific hack, which is based on an earlier "star" hack. For example:

```
*+html p { font-size: 5em; }
```

> This code will be applied in Internet Explorer 7, but not in any other
>   browser. Note that this hack only works in IE7 standards mode; it does
>   not work in quirks mode. This hack is also supported by Internet
>   Explorer 8's compatibility view (IE7 standards mode), but not in IE8
>   standards mode. Like the star HTML hack, this uses valid CSS

As Marc B mentioned in the comments, it's an IE hack that works because of a mysterious parent element that IE used to employ:

> The html element is the root element of the W3C standard DOM, but
>   Internet Explorer versions 4 through 6 include a mysterious parent
>   element.[8] Fully compliant browsers will ignore the * html selector,
>   while IE4-6 will process it normally. This enables rules to be
>   specified for these versions of Internet Explorer which will be
>   ignored by all other browsers. For example, this rule specifies text
>   size in Internet Explorer 4-6, but not in any other browsers.